# Will installing Django on Linux VPS server, cause any issue to live sites

Tags: linux, php, centos, python

I have my live sites running on Linux VPS. Now i want to install Django on that.
I just want to make sure that will it be safe. Will it interfere in current php sites running with apache.

Any particular file/files i can backup , just in case problem occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no definitive "Yes" or "No". Its always good to have a backup. If you misconfigure it, yes ist can affect the whole VPS but this is not necessarily the case. There is always the chance that something goes wrong. The question is too generic to give a qualified answer. Try it, if it fails then recover your backup.

Comment: By Backup, i want to know is there any specific files rather than full backup , to save just for worst case thing. i mean websites needs apache,php . i am not touching php , so apache is where something can go wrong. so any particular files of apache

Comment: I haven't worked with CentOS so far but there are numerous ways. What VPS provider are you on? Did they have a backup feature, that would be the easiest way in my opinion. There are also script at the CentOS wiki: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/ As for apache alone I would backup httpd.conf and the DocumentRoot.